# How to clear all bits above a certain bit position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bit manipulation question in Javascript.

I have a number that I need to clear some upper bits from. Which exact bits need to be cleared is determined programmatically and as a result of some calculation, I have two pieces of information, a bit position and a mask for that particular bit position.  What I want to do is to clear all the bits above that bit position (not include that bit) in my value.

So, if my value is:

```
 0b11111111
```

And, a calculation has yielded bit position 3 and a mask for that bit position:

```
 0b00000100
```

I want to mask out or clear the bits above that bit position 3 in my value and end up with:

```
 0b00000111
```

As a reminder, the bit position that I want to clear above is programmatically determined and could be any bit position so I can't just code a pre-defined mask.  How would I do that?  Programming environment is Javascript in node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 value & ((mask << 1) - 1)
```

In the example given, `100` leftshifted by 1 will be `1000` (8) minus one will be `111` (7). `value & 111` will clear all bits except the last three. Might not work with more than 30 bits. If 31 bits are needed, one could also use a very similar formula:

```
value & (mask * 2 - 1)
```

The logic is pretty much the same, but as the multiplication gets performed on a 52 bit mantissa, you get one bit more.

Comment: Excellent.  It works.  Forgot about the -1 option.  I'm well aware of the bit limitations.  I'm using 31 bits per value.

Comment: Great. The last sentence is adressed to future "copy & pasters" ... :)

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like I do have to make sure and not run this for bit position 31 (there is actually nothing to clear in that case anyway), because I think `mask << 1` would spill into the sign bit and mess things up.

Comment: right, it would work if JS would do integer substraction, however as `- 1` gets performed on a 64bit floating point, that won't work. Not sure if handling that edge case is simpler than building up the mask in another way.

Comment: Wait, what about `mask * 2 - 1` ?

Comment: That would probably work too and then perhaps not have the sign bit overflow issue.